# How to transform predicted results when doing cross-validation in sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, pipeline, cross-validation

I had posted [this question on Data Science StackExchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/68998/how-to-transform-predicted-results-when-doing-cross-validation-in-sklearn) but got no answers. Someone suggested me to move the question here because it looks like a programming question, so I have a try.

> I want to do cross-validation in sklearn like below, but the predicted
>   result of X still need to be transformed to reduce the distance from
>   y. How to do that with adding a custom function?

```
model = XGBRegressor(n_estimator = 500,
                     learn_rate = 0.05,
                     random_state = 0)

pipeline = Pipeline( steps = [('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                            ('model', model)
                            ])

scores = -1 * cross_val_score(pipeline, X, y,
                            cv = 3,
                            scoring = 'neg_mean_absolute_error',
                            verbose = 0)
```

> There are only 0 and 1 in y, so I want to round and cut decimals off
>   in the result of X, just after the step for predicting of X.

I maybe need other operations on y in the future. For example, fitting the correct result only includes the numbers like 0.5, 1.5, 2.5 ...

Example:

X - The input

```
ID Column_1 Column_2 Column_3
0    'A'       10     True
1    'A'       20     False
2    'B'       30     True
```

y - The correct result

```
ID Result
0  1
1  0
2  1
```

The current output

```
ID Result
0   0.899
1  -0.001
2   1.102
```

The expected output

```
ID Result
0    1
1    0
2    1
```

Comment: Could you please provide us with an example of the expected result ? Something like input of the function -> output

Comment: @t_e_o OK, I have added the example.

Comment: have you tried using `XGBClassifier`? Any reason you have to use a regressor?

Comment: @ShihabShahriarKhan I have tried `XGBClassifier`, but it's hard to predict exact values if the correct result only includes numbers like 0.5, 1.5, 2.5 ...